# Converting time4j Duration<IsoUnit> from P365D to P1Y and so on

Tags: java, duration, time4j

```java
Instant i1 = Instant.now();
Instant i2 = Instant.now().plusSeconds(60 * 60 * 24 * 365);
Duration<IsoUnit> dur = Duration.from((TemporalAmount) java.time.Duration.between(i1, i2));
System.out.println(dur);
```

this code prints P365D, is there a way to make units fill up the next bigger unit, so this becomes P1Y and if i had like P334D to P11M and so on?

time4j version is 4.38

Comment: Year may have 365 or 366 days. How would you know which one to choose? The same is for month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other comments and answers are completely right to say that a year is not always equal to 365 days.

The Time4J-method [net.time4j.Duration.from(TemporalAmount)](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/Duration.html#from-java.time.temporal.TemporalAmount-) returns a normalized duration using `STD_PERIOD` as normalizer. The documentation of this normalizer says:

> Normalizes the duration items on the base of 1 year = 12 months and 1
>   day = 24 hours and 1 hour = 60 minutes and 1 minute = 60 seconds -
>   without converting days to months.

So you can only expect the result to be in days when you start with a temporal amount defined in seconds.

If you still want a year then I suggest you to first convert your instants to calendar dates using an appropriate time zone. But in leap years, your code would still produce 365 days and not a year after having added `60 * 60 * 24 * 365` seconds to the second instant. So your addition of seconds is also flawed because it is based on false assumptions.

### Side note:

If you want the reverse way, namely how many seconds are in a year then you might use code like

```
Moment m1 = Moment.nowInSystemTime();
Moment m2 = m1.toZonalTimestamp(ZonalOffset.UTC).plus(1, CalendarUnit.YEARS).atUTC();
long seconds = SI.SECONDS.between(m1, m2); // = 366 days in seconds if applied on date 2019-05-22!
```

With a future version of Time4J and possible leap second at the end of year 2019, the code might even produce an extra second.

### Anyway, I advise you to update Time4J to v5.4 and consider following mappings:

```
java.time.Instant as input => net.time4j.MachineTime.from(...)
java.time.LocalDateTime/net.time4j.PlainTimestamp => net.time4j.Duration.from(...)
```

So if you really want years as possible output in printing durations and you have instants/moments then first convert to LocalDateTime/PlainTimestamp (using a time zone or offset) before you create the appropriate duration object.

### Update from 2019-05-25:

Another way with the version v5.4 (or later) is possible via "fuzzy" durations. You could normalize the durations you get by applying an approximation. Example:

```
    Duration<IsoUnit> d = Duration.of(60 * 60 * 24 * 365, ClockUnit.SECONDS);
    d = d.with(Duration.approximateMaxUnitOnly());
    System.out.println(d); // P1Y
```

Due to the nature of this kind of normalization, you cannot expect exact results.

Answer (score 1):

A year doesn't have a fixed amount of seconds:

1. Leap years have an additional day on February 29
2. [Leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) are sometimes added

Due to above you have to know how many seconds are in a year. It seems like instead of `Instant` and `Duration` you should be using `LocalDate` and `Period` (at least when using `java.time`):

```
LocalDate d1 = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate d2 = d1.plusYears(1);
Period p = Period.between(d1, d2);
System.out.println(p); // P1Y
```